# WPF: DataGrid with a tree-column in an MVVM Windows application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, tree, hierarchical-data

Here is a rephrased version of my issue:

Here is a screenshot of the result I'm looking for (from an older, non C#/WPF version of the application):
[image: target]

Looks like all the other grid-tree-views and what [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/download.html) provides. But unfortunately I have some rules I have to follow:

- WPF
- MVVM
- Just a DataGrid and its components must be used (no TreeView, ListView, etc.)
- The Items are hold in an `ObservableCollection<T>` where `T.Property1`, `T.Property2` etc hold the data for the columns of the `DataGrid`.
- The lower Levels of an item are hold in `T.PropertyChilds` of type `ObservableCollection<T>` and are not known/filled beforehand. They must be loaded on the first exand of the item.

Here is a screenshot of similar data and what I've got so far in WPF/C#:
[image: current WPF]

It looks like a standard DataGrid. But which columns it can hold, which property of T the columns are showing, which columns are currently visible, etc is defined by a own framework around the DataGrid which basically just adds columns to the `public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns` Collection of a `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`.

My task is now to do a new class derived from `DataGridColumn` which can display and load the hierarchical data structure of my ViewModel described above.

The main problems I'm facing are as far as I can tell:
- how to visibly display the levels like a treeview in a DataGrid column
- how to process the loaded data from childs so they are shown as in the first screenshot above. Do I have to do a flat `ObservableCollection<T>` where I add the loaded ChildData and some extra properties like level and parent - or is it possible to define a kindo of a hierarchical data template for a DataGrid?

Thanks a lot
Soko

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. At least post a screenshot of what you need.

Comment: Sorry for that. Please see my rephrased version above. It seems I'm in too deep in this issue at the moment and thought I made myself clear